# Script type unwanted string added before type

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Here in my html I used like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.example.com/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

But in my view when I try to see page source it becomes

```
<script type="70b8453d7dd98ccaf7071668-text/javascript" src='https://www.example.com/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

How this changing I can't understand 
**type="70b8453d7dd98ccaf7071668-**

Please suggest

Comment: try disabling all plugin and change theme.

Comment: Are you using any module bundler ( webpack , rollup ) to generate this html?

Comment: Get rid of the type attribute, you don't need it anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Plugins**
Are you using any kind of caching/asset optimization plugins? If yes try disabling them and then check.

---

**Modules**
Check your server settings. See if you have any modules enabled. Such as [Google Pagespeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/)

---

**Browser extension**
Maybe it is an extension fiddling with your DOM. Try checking the source in a different browser.

---

Share the entire page source code if none of these solutions work.